# printf inside variadic function prints garbage

Tags: c, printf

I am trying to create a customizable debug library so I can declare my debug function outside and set it to the library as a callback, so others libraries can call this debug functions without knowing how are defined those callbacks.

My debug.c file contains the following extracts:

```
// NOTE: type defined in .h as: typedef void(*debug_custom_callback_t)(const char *format, ...);
debug_custom_callback_t debug_custom_callback[DEBUG_NUM_CALLBACKS];


void debug_log_printf(uint8_t idx, const char *format, ...){

   va_list args;

    // callback exists
    if(debug_custom_callback[idx]){
        va_start(args, format);
        debug_custom_callback[idx](format, args);
        va_end(args);
    }
    
}

void debug_set_callback(uint8_t idx, debug_custom_callback_t callback){

   //callback assigning
   if(callback && idx < DEBUG_NUM_CALLBACKS)
      debug_custom_callback[idx] = callback;

}
```

This library has is own makefile so it can be compiled as a .a lib and is being linked with -l flag in the makefile of the main code.

Main code uses debug library as follows:

```
   ...
   
   //main code
   
   uint8_t test = 0xFF;
   
   debug_set_callback(0, main_printf);
   debug_log_printf(0, "Testing %d %d\n", test, 1); // prints: Testing -1095376668 -1225391600
   
   ...
   
   
   
   //Definition of main_printf
   void main_printf(const char *format, ...){
       va_list args;

       va_start(args, format);
       printf(format, args);
       va_end(args);
    }
```

But this is not working fine. The string is printed properly, but any value that I try to print is printed as garbage. As you can see, even the constants are being printed badly.

What am I missing?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `printf(format, args);` is nonsense. You want to use one of the variadic print functions for that. See [`vprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfprintf), for example. Regular `printf` doesn't just magically see you're sending a `va_list` and react accordingly. Similarly, `main_printf` shouldn't even use variadic arguments; it should use a `va_list` as well. You can only take one shot to unpackage a `...` into a `va_list`. Everything thereon down should be `va_list`. Your shot comes at `debug_log_printf`. From there on it needs to be `va_list` turtles.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you for your reply! You are so right, it was completely nonsense. Now I'm using vprintf and va_list for callbacks and everything is working fine. Thank you very much :) By the way... turtles? Is `va_list` mechanism slow?

Comment: Loosely (and apparently poorly) referring to [Turtles all the way down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down).

Comment: @WhozCraig I would like to choose yours as the best answer, can you post it on answers field? so I could do it

Comment: areify, Tip: In a _debug_ function, validate the arguments. Make sure `idx` is in range and `format != NULL`.  The whole point of debug code is that data is not always as expected.

Comment: @areify Andrejs already has it going-on. I've already upticked that answer, and if it fits your bill, I'd suggest the same and select it as the outright answer.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't into comments when I wrote my answer. Since @WhozCraig was first to provide correct solution, I'm ok with removing my answer and giving a credit to him.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs No worries, mate. It's totally fine.

Comment: @WhozCraig no problem, I'll choose then Andrejs answer. Thank you both for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `vprintf` instead.

```c
void main_printf(const char *fmt, va_list args) {
    vprintf(fmt, args);
}
```